# Determining The Truth Value Of Quantified Statements

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

The problem I am working on is:

> Determine the truth value of each of these statements if
>   the domain consists of all integers.
>
> a) $∀n(n+1>n)$
>
> b) $∃n(2n=3n)$
>
> c) $∃n(n=−n)$
>
> d) $∀n(3n≤4n)$

---

The only part I am having difficulty with is part (d). The answer key declares that this statement is true. But isn't it really a false statement? Wouldn't any negative number render this statement false?

Comment: I think the domain is positive integers for the d part or maybe you should think of the negative integers as -1.n, $n\in Z^+$, so when you multiply the inequality with -1, the direction of the inequality changes.

Comment: Which would make perfect sense, if they had specified that the domain was in fact positive integers. So, can I just conclude that the answer key is wrong?

Comment: The answer key is wrong -- since (c) only makes sense if the domain is positive and negative integers, and presumably the same domain is to be assumed in (c) and (d).

Comment: @PeterSmith Well, c) is true for the value 0.

Comment: @EliMackenzie It seems the answer key has some problems, for the d part my explanations seems correct (please look and if it's wrong inform me), but 0 is definetely true in c part, so yes the domain is problematic.

Comment: The answer key is clearly wrong for (d).

Comment: @ciceksizkakarot: Yes, (d) would be true if the domain had been given as the positive (or the non-negative) integers, but the remainder of your comment really doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yeah, it really seems that the answer key is wrong.

Comment: @EliMackenzie But think: what are we to make of the negative sign in (c)???

Comment: @PeterSmith $-1 \cdot 0 = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the domain of $n$, as stated, is all* $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then your reasoning is correct and $d$ is indeed false. Negative integers would serve as your counterexample showing the statement is false. So the answer key must be wrong, or there was a typo in the problem set!

---

If the domain of $n$ were $\mathbb{N}$, and depending on how one defines the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$: would is any integer $n \geq 0$ (or an integer $n\geq 1$).

Hence, in either case, negative numbers are excluded from the domain of $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence, $(d)$ would be true, if the domain were in fact $n \geq 0$: given ANY $n\in \mathbb{N},\;3n\leq 4n$, since $3\leq 4$ is clearly true.

---

Comment: @amWhy Yes, and thank you very much!